# Annotations not showing in 3D Plotly line chart with custom button

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, annotations, plotly-python

Annotations are not showing when clicking a custom button. What I wanted was to show line annotations by clicking the button. They're not showing; only line ID "Member 35" is written at the bottom left with my current code (below).

I think it's a position problem or some problem with defining annotation; it's not clear to me. I've searched for a solution multiple times but have not been able to find one.

- `xxx` is some 2D array of length `tmm`
- `mem_index` contains member IDs

```
        anno=[]
        for i in range(0,tmm,2):
            
            fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=xxx[i:i+2,2],y=xxx[i:i+2,0],z=xxx[i:i+2,1], mode='lines',      
                line=dict(
                        color="black",                
                        width=10),))

            ax= xxx[i,2].item() 
            bx= xxx[i+1,2].item() 
            ay= xxx[i,0].item() 
            by= xxx[i+1,0].item() 
            az= xxx[i,1].item() 
            bz= xxx[i+1,1].item() 

            x_annotate=((ax+bx)/2)+0.1
            y_annotate=((ay+by)/2)+0.1
            z_annotate=((az+bz)/2)+0.1
            
            #(x_annotate, y_annotate, z_annotate)
            a1= dict(
            showarrow=False,
            x=x_annotate,
            y=y_annotate,
            z=z_annotate,
            text=f"Member {mem_index[kk]}",
            font=dict(
                color="black",
                size=8
            ),)

            anno.append(a1)
            kk= kk+1

      button1= [True for i in range ( fig2)]

      Model.update_layout(
            updatemenus=[
                dict(
                    type = "buttons",
                    direction = "left",
                    buttons=list([
                        dict(
                            args=[{'visible': button1},
                                  {"title": "RC Model",
                                    "annotations": []}],
                            label="RC Model",
                            method="update",
                        ),
                        dict(
                            args=[{'visible': button1},
                                  {"title": "Members ID's",
                                    "annotations": anno}],
                            label="Member Ids",
                            method="update"
                        ),
                   
                    pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
                    showactive=True,
                    x=0.11,
                    xanchor="left",
                    y=1.1,
                    yanchor="middle"
                ),
            ]
        )

        Model.update_layout(height=800, width=800)
        Model.show()
```

[image]

Comment: can you include enough code for your figure to be fully reproducible? what are `mem_index`, `anno_member`, `f3` supposed to be?

Comment: I have edited the code to make it clear. **mem_index** contains member ID, and have replaced other two.  Data contained by xxx is too big and is calculated, therefore not possible for me to add it over here. I will generate some small figure to add here.

Comment: @John Collins, Thanks a lot its working. mode= "text" is the only way I think. Adding annotation in button for 2D is  working but fails in 3D plots.

Comment: Click event is very limited in plotly plots, is there any Python libraries that can handle click events effective in 3D

Comment: Well, that is where Plotly Dash comes in. With Plotly Dash you could do just about anything you can imagine, and all in Python. You would write a callback function whose input is the click event on the plot, and as a `State` input to the same callback function include the current state of all plotted data, then re-analyze and output the plot with whatever hover or any other kind of visual effect desired. If you're interested you could open a new question and I could demonstrate if you describe what click event functionality you want. It may work I would have to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could try plotting another plotly 3D Scatter object for every line, except using `mode='text'`, as a workaround for implementing 3D line text annotations

It was a little difficult to recreate your problem and the code below will have to be adapted for your specific implementation and data structures; but, hopefully this helps move you forward with what you're trying to do. What I've done below is recreated your screenshot by an approximation using a plot cube function. Then I name every line making up the cubic mesh 3D structure with a "Member X" ID using an additional `fig.add_trace` call, per line.

<sup>***Note***: This demo approach results in many overlapping labels, hence the quirk of a jiggle "`shift`" function I've added; you likely may not need that.</sup>

```py
import random

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


def add_cube(fig, origin, size=1, line_id_start=0):
    """
    Add a cube to a Plotly figure.
    
    Parameters:
        fig (go.Figure): The Plotly figure to which the cube will be added.
        origin (tuple): Coordinates (x, y, z) representing the bottom-left-front corner of the cube.
        size (int, optional): The side length of the cube.
        line_id_start (int, optional): The starting line ID for annotation.
    
    Returns:
        int: `line_id` for keeping track of how many lines have been traced.
    """

    def shift():
        """Random jiggle for moving overlapping labels.
        
        Returns:
            float: A small (non-zero) number -0.1 < x < 0.1.
        """
        return (random.randint(0, 100) / 1e3) * random.choice([1, -1])

    x0, y0, z0 = origin
    line_id = line_id_start
    for dx in [0, size]:
        for dy in [0, size]:
            for coords in [
                ([x0 + dx, x0 + dx], [y0, y0 + size], [z0, z0]),
                ([x0 + dx, x0 + dx], [y0 + dy, y0 + dy], [z0, z0 + size]),
                ([x0, x0 + size], [y0 + dy, y0 + dy], [z0 + dx, z0 + dx]),
            ]:
                x, y, z = coords
                x_annotate, y_annotate, z_annotate = (
                    np.mean(x) + shift(),
                    np.mean(y) + shift(),
                    np.mean(z) + shift(),
                )
                fig.add_trace(
                    go.Scatter3d(
                        x=x,
                        y=y,
                        z=z,
                        mode="lines",
                        line=dict(color="black", width=5),
                    )
                )
                fig.add_trace(
                    go.Scatter3d(
                        x=[x_annotate],
                        y=[y_annotate],
                        z=[z_annotate],
                        mode="text",
                        text=[f"Member {line_id}"],
                        name=f"Member {line_id}",
                        visible=False,
                    )
                )
                line_id += 1
    return line_id


fig = go.Figure()

# Add cubes to the figure
n_cubes = 3  # Number of cubes
total_lines = 0

for i in range(n_cubes):
    for j in range(
        n_cubes - 1
    ):  # Minus 1 results in a 3x2 cube like shown in OP question
        for k in range(n_cubes):
            total_lines = add_cube(fig, (i, j, k), line_id_start=total_lines,)

# Update layout with buttons
show_labels = [True for _ in range(len(fig.data))]
hide_labels = [True if (x % 2 == 0) else False for x in range(len(fig.data))]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            x=0.1,
            y=0.95,
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label="Member IDs",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {"visible": show_labels},
                        {"title": "3D Cubic Mesh Plot ~ Member IDs"},
                    ],
                ),
                dict(
                    label="Turn Off Labels",
                    method="update",
                    args=[
                        {"visible": hide_labels},
                        {"title": "3D Cubic Mesh Plot"},
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]
)

fig.update_layout(height=800, width=800)
fig.show()
```

produces this functionality:

[image: Video screen shot recording of 3D plotly text annotated plot]

And a very slightly different version of the above code (where I only assigned text labels if the `line_id` modulo 12 was > 4 and < 9; just a quick hack to diminish the excess of labels - these specific aspects of the code will obviously be not exactly relevant to your implementation but were needed for me to demonstrate) gave:
[image: Slightly altered code output of same plot as above]